# Why does my modal not work? Bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I wonder why my Bootstrap 4 modal is not working. Any clue? I literally copy and paste from the Bootstrap 4 website (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#live-demo) Also, I have added js that they say.

Please find below the code.

Thanks

I have checked other posts and I didn't have luck

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta content="Description" name="description">
  <meta content="index,follow" name="robots">
  <link href="/images/myicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">
  <title>TITLE HERE</title>
  <!--CSS-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Bootstrap CSS JS-->
  <!--fonts-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--CB-modal -->
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<!-- JS code -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<!--JS below-->


<!--modal-->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#MyModal").modal();
  });
  })
</script>



</html>
```

Comment: It says in the console that you have a syntax error. Try to run your code snippet, you'll see it too.

Comment: you have specified $("#MyModal") selector and your modal id is id="myModal" correct it. also data-target="#exampleModal" is wrong as your modal id is "myModal"

Comment: This mistake actually appears to be in made in the v4 documentation. Not difficult to catch if you're paying attention but annoying that copy/pasting pure example doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are typo in your snippet (unused `});` at the end), but most importantly your toggle button is targeting the wrong modal id. Make sure `data-target` is the id of the modal you're targeting:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Demo:

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<!--CB-modal -->
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- JS code -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<!--JS below-->


<!--modal-->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal();
  });
</script>



</html>
```

**Edit**: Updated Bootstrap 4-beta as per @OlavT request:

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<!--CB-modal -->
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- JS code -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--JS below-->


<!--modal-->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal();
  });
</script>



</html>
```

Comment: Has anyone tested this with Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta? I couldn't get the modal to show.

Comment: @OlavTI got it running just fine. Are you sure you imported all needed files? See my edited answer for v4-beta demo.

Comment: I got it to work again. Seems that it was caused with some issues with my local popper.js file. When using it from a CDN it works fine.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap version 4 beta 2. The Modal opens up but the whole page (including the modal itself is dim) As I understand the page below it is supposed to get dim but not the modal itself. And the close buttons are not clickable for me. It stays open even when I click on the page outside the modal.

Answer (score 1):

You have some script error and your  `data-target="#exampleModal"` does not match with the model's ID

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta content="Description" name="description">
  <meta content="index,follow" name="robots">
  <link href="/images/myicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">
  <title>TITLE HERE</title>
  <!--CSS-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Bootstrap CSS JS-->
  <!--fonts-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--CB-modal -->
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<!-- JS code -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<!--JS below-->


<!--modal-->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#MyModal").modal();
     $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#myInput').focus();
     });
  });
</script>



</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I landed here because I was having the same error.  After going back and reading a bit. I ran into the following:

If you’re using our compiled JavaScript, don’t forget to include CDN versions of jQuery and Popper.js before it.

Because I downloaded bootstrap 4 and copied the folders as I used to with bootstrap v3, I assumed it was all going to work.

Download section has the CDN for popper and jQuery

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/

hope this helps... Nessio

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#MyModal").modal();
     $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#myInput').focus();
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data-target name you entered in not correct.
Here is the correct code of your button

```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

your data target is wrong: `#exampleModal`, should be `#myModal`.

also, you have incorrect syntax in your js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#MyModal").modal();
  });
  })//remove this
```

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myInput').focus()
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta content="Description" name="description">
  <meta content="index,follow" name="robots">
  <link href="/images/myicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">
  <title>TITLE HERE</title>
  <!--CSS-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Bootstrap CSS JS-->
  <!--fonts-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--CB-modal -->
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<!-- JS code -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<!--JS below-->


<!--modal-->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#MyModal").modal();
  });
</script>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error but for a different reason(...rather silly). I was using `thymeleaf layout` and accidentally put the `modal div` outside the `content fragment`.

```
<div layout:fragment="content">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#someId">Open</button>
...
</div>
<div class="modal" id="someId">
</div>
```

So, although the `modal div` was present in the code, it was not rendered on the `DOM`(checked with `View Page Source`). It fails silently without any errors/warnings. **Please ensure that the `modal div` is rendered on the `DOM`.**

Answer (score 0):

My issue was exactly explained here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49039205/9855327
In my case, it is not related with wrong references id, it was because I created a modal inside a table in a loop in C# / Aspnet MVC. Se I created a modal for each table row.

I just inserted the code below at the end body tag:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery("body").children().first().before($(".modal"));
});
</script>
```

It will move all modals HTML elements to the beginning of the body and for me was enough.